# Ansible still requires root password?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set up an Ansible lab to use passwordless ssh, which seems to work fine.  I can ssh into my server with no pw via the terminal, but if I try to make changes on the remote server that require root access, it fails.

I've found using `become: true` and `--ask-for-pass` in my tasks it works, so I know its related to permissions on the remote server? Is become and `--ask-for-pass` necessary? Is this how everyone uses Ansible? Thanks in advance!

/BG

Comment: Have a look at `ansible-playbook --help`. The option to provide the become password on the command line is `-K, --ask-become-pass`

Comment: You will be interested in the following documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a command on the remote server that requires root privileges, you need to add `become: true` to your playbook. This will make Ansible to use `sudo` when running the command.

If you don't pass the password with `--ask-for-pass` then you should enable passwordless sudo for the user running the command. Otherwise you cannot run the command because of permissions.